# Code taking forever to execute under certain conditions. Needs to run faster

Tags: python, permutation

This code is part of a challenge that requires the code to give back permutations of a string with no duplicates. The code executes but under some of the challenges it doesn't pass because of the time gate and i dont know a way to make it execute faster.

```
from itertools import permutations as perm

def permutations(string):
    permList = list(perm(string))
    joinedList = [''.join(tups) for tups in permList]
    ans = []
    [ans.append(x) for x in joinedList if x not in ans]
    return ans
```

Again code runs for certain examples but examples with large strings and alot of matches the code takes too long and fails the challenge.

Comment: the `x not in ans` part probably takes loads of time, because every time it's called it has to check the whole ans list. You could optimize it a little by saving permutations in a dictionary, and that way you can check for duplicate by calling `dict.get(x)` while having your values stored in `dict.keys()` iterator

Comment: Note on that second to last line: You're using a list comprehension as a normal `for` loop (I suppose to save a few lines of code), but the purpose of list comprehensions is to build lists, not save lines of code. However the `for` loop you're doing actually builds a list anyway. Would be improved by changing to: `return [x for x in joinedList if x not in ans]` (and saves 2 lines of code—if you care about that sort of thing).

Comment: @Henry But ans is empty, so the result of that list would be every element in joinedList

Comment: @cricket_007 oh yes, good catch, well then it seems it's just to remove duplicates, which can be done with `return list(set(ans))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent duplicates, use a set, not lists. Your code takes forever because you're constantly scanning the list while you are inserting new data. Instead you can do a constant time lookup / replacement

And you can save on storage costs by using generator comprehension rather than list comprehension

```
def permutations(string):
    permList = (''.join(p) for p in perm(string)))
    result = set()
    for p in permList:
        result.add(p)
    return list(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should keep the output in a generator for as long as possible; evaluating it takes time and space.

Here we maintain a set of seen elements in order to avoid yielding them again thus keeping each unique.

```
import itertools

def unique_permutations(seq):
    seen = set()
    for p in itertools.permutations(seq):
        if p not in seen:
            seen.add(p)
            yield(p)

for p in unique_permutations('aaab'):
    print(p)
```